# Obtener fechas para quincenas a partir de una fecha determinada. C#

Tags: c#, busqueda-rango-de-fechas

Necesito obtener una lista con las fechas de los días 15s y 30s (28 en caso de que el mes sea febrero) a partir de una fecha determinada.
Por ejemplo, si tengo como fecha dada el 02/01/2023, y necesito obtener las siguientes 5 quincenas, debería obtener lo siguiente:

```
15/01/2023
30/01/2023
15/02/2023
28/02/2023
15/03/2023
```

Tengo el siguiente código en visual Basic, pero necesito hacerlo en c#

```
Function CalcQuincenas(ByVal Qnas As Integer, ByVal Fecha As Date) As String
    

    Dim dia, mes, año As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim Fechas As String = ""
    Dim UltDia As Integer


    dia = DateAndTime.Day(Fecha) : mes = Month(Fecha) : año = Year(Fecha)

    For x = 1 To Qnas
        Fechas = ""
        If dia <= 15 Then
            Fechas = DateSerial(año, mes, 15) & " "
            dia = 16
        Else

            UltDia = DateAndTime.Day(DateSerial(año, mes + 1, 0))

            If UltDia = 31 Then
                Fechas = DateSerial(año, mes + 1, -1) & " "
            Else
                Fechas = DateSerial(año, mes + 1, 0) & " "
            End If

            mes = mes + 1
            dia = 15
        End If
    Next
    CalcQuincenas = Fechas
End Function
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y cual el es problema??? el codigo es practicamente el mismo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

te hice una demo de cómo se haría en c# por lo que sé la primera quincena del mes siempre es 15 días y l'última coge todos los días, así que hice una demo para la forma que pedias y comente la que yo creía que es la correcta.

Función:

```
 private static List<string> CalcQuincenas(int v, DateTime date) // el static es porque lo prove en consola
    {
       List<string> listastrings= new List<string>();
        int i= 0;
        while ( i < v)
        {
            if (date.Day <= 15)
            {
               date= date.AddDays(16-date.Day);
                listastrings.Add("15/" + date.Month + "/" + date.Year);
                i++;
            }
            //else//las quincenas contando la segunda quincena como todo el resto del mes
            //{
            //    listastrings.Add(DateTime.DaysInMonth(date.Year, date.Month) + "/" + date.Month + "/" + date.Year);
            //    date = new DateTime(date.Year,date.Month+1,1);
            //    i++;
            //}
            else //las  quincenas como las tienes en vbs
            {
                if(date.Month==2)
                    listastrings.Add("28" + "/" + date.Month + "/" + date.Year);
                else
                    listastrings.Add("30"+ "/" + date.Month + "/" + date.Year);
                date = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1).AddMonths(1);
                i++;

            }

            
        }
        return listastrings;
    }
```

Llamar:

```
       List<string> st= CalcQuincenas(5,new DateTime(2023,1,2));
        foreach(string s in st)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias, esto es lo que necesitaba. Saludos.